# How to prevent user to change recipient address when MetaMask transaction window pops up?

Tags: web3js, transactions, metamask, web3-providers, payments

I want to integrate MetaMask as one of payment methods on my website.
The idea is to lock my content, when user made a successful ETH payment so the content will be revealed.
This is the source code:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@metamask/legacy-web3@latest/dist/metamask.web3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button class="pay-button">Pay</button>
    <div id="status"></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
      if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
          await ethereum.enable();
          initPayButton()
        } catch (err) {
          $('#status').html('User denied account access', err)
        }
      } else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
        initPayButton()
      } else {
        $('#status').html('No Metamask (or other Web3 Provider) installed')
      }
    })

    const initPayButton = () => {
      $('.pay-button').click(() => {
        // paymentAddress is where funds will be send to
        const paymentAddress = '0x9e76F53cC098acF725927Df7d6Ca35b6D0063e2c'
        const amountEth = 0.5

        web3.eth.sendTransaction({
          to: paymentAddress,
          value: web3.toWei(amountEth, 'ether')
        }, (err, transactionId) => {
          if  (err) {
            console.log('Payment failed', err)
            $('#status').html('<p style="color: red;">Payment failed</p>')
          } else {
            console.log('Payment successful', transactionId)
            $('#status').html('<p>style="color: green;"Payment successful</p>')
          }
        })
      })
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/iwolfcode/uqdptcw8/4/

But the problem is, when the MetaMask transaction window pops up, user still can change the `paymentAddress` (recipient address) then confirm and he will get the successful status.
Is there a way to prevent this? or is there any other way to sovle the problem?

[image: How to disable this?]

Thank you guys so much.

Comment: I think you can add some sort of check in the back end of your app so that you can check if the transactions details actually correspond to the initial values you were supposed to have before the editing.

Comment: Why not to tie your front end to a smart contract that keeps track of all payments in a mapping, reading if the connected account paid? if paid show contents, if not request payment.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this because MetaMask does not provide such user experience.

If users mess up their own payment then you can blame the user.